# Retrieve part of text

Tags: xpath

I have following XPath to retrieve the sentence:

```
{//node/node/node/node[@class='InfoType18']/metalist/meta[@name='custom.ECO.regul1'],' (')}
```

Result is then:

```
This is a test (EU) 206/2012
```

I work with a dropdown menu, so the total characters of text will change.
There are 2 parts:
1) The part before (EU) 206/2012
2) The part (EU) 206/2012

Problem 1:
I already solved: to retrieve the text before the (EU) code:

```
{substring-before(//node/node/node/node[@class='InfoType18']/metalist/meta[@name='custom.ECO.regul1'],' (')}
```

Problem 2:
I don't find a manner because I can't say: substring-before the (EU) because text length is variable.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Can you post the html you're working with?

Comment: It's a very big xml file with layout definition etc.
It's not a document of 10 lines but of 100.000 lines.

Comment: It's like described: 1 single sentence has to be cutted in 2 parts.
Part 1 before the "("-sign is OK, but now I still need the part starting from the "(" until the end. Keep in mind that length of part 1 and 2 is variable.

Comment: Can you provide more examples of your input data and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [`substring-after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/substring-after) it works the same way as `substring-before`.

So the xPath to retrieve the part after (EU) is the following:

```
substring-after(//node/node/node/node[@class='InfoType18']/metalist/meta[@name='custom.ECO.regul1'],')')
```

And the text's length shouldn't matter in this case.

Comment: First I should say: No it isn't what I want because I need also the (EU), but then came the fantastic idea to insert the (EU) as a neutral element between the first xpath who cuts the part before the "(" and the part that you now suggest. I may be happy that all entries in the selection lists are (EU) :) Thanks!!!!!!